# Creating our own normal distribution function in R

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I have a homework question which requires me to create my own standard normal distribution function which I had derived. Nonetheless, I have problem doing so.

What I did was to have two independent uniformly distributed random variable and perform a box muller transformation on it according to [this link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Box-MullerTransformation.html).

Nonetheless, when I plot out my graph, I didn't get the plot I want. This is my plot [image: Incorrect]

But I believe the true plot should be something like this: [image: Correct Image]

Am I doing it wrongly ?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to reproduce your issue.  But I would guess this will end up being a more appropriate question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) than SO.  If the link between your stats and your code is off, you'll get a better and/or faster answer on CV than on SO.

Comment: please provide the code and data. it's not very clear what you have done

Comment: can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your on the right track. I played with the link you provided and it seems to work. It might be some minor error in your code.

```
vec1 <- runif(10000)
vec2 <- runif(10000)

z1 <- c(NA)
z2 <- c(NA)

z1 <- sqrt(-2*log(vec1))*cos(2*pi*vec2)
z2 <- sqrt(-2*log(vec2))*cos(2*pi*vec1)
```

And when putting it into a QQ-plot I get:

[image]

Comment: what are your `z1 <- c(NA); z2 <- c(NA)` for?  They look useless ...

Comment: Ah! Thank you for noting this. They originally had a use but changed the entire setup which made them redundant.